# Twitter widget on mobile Ionic

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, twitter, ionic-framework

How do I implement Twitter widget on my mobile app? I'm doing it this way, it's working on `ionic serve`  but when I try to build the apk, it's not working on the mobile. I'm doing it this way.

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/thev_official">Tweets by thev_official</a>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script>window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    t = window.twttr || {};
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

  t._e = [];
  t.ready = function(f) {
    t._e.push(f);
  };

  return t;
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));</script>
```

This is how I did it since I managed the facebook widget to work in the same way.

Comment: Hello, I've tested your code on my phone and it is working fine ! Furthermore, I've found that this line `<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>` is useless since you are injecting the script just under. Plus, if you do this on device, it will inject `file://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js` and not `https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js` because the other file are loading from `file://`. Maybe you should take a look on the chrome debug console on your device to find the issue.

Comment: yep i forgot to comment out the first script.. hmm, it's probably depending on the version of android. what's your version of android? mine is 4.4.4,

Comment: I also forgot to mention that there's no error on console.. may I know the version/OS of phone where you've tried?

Comment: It was a nexus5x (android 6). You can also try on emulators to help you. Please verify the internet connection. I have but your code on index.html of a blank starter app of ionic if it might help you.

Comment: Hmm, I tried on Android 5 still not working.. I'm sure it's not internet connection since I have a facebook widget above this twitter and it's working